# how to check whether a text file in MATLAB exists

Tags: matlab, file-io

I need to check whether a text file in a folder exists. If it does, I need to load the value from the text file. If not, I need to carry on with the next iteration.

I know how to load the value from the text file using the function called load.

e.g.

```
emo = load(fullfile(BASE_DIR,List1(3).name));
```

But I'm not sure how to check whether a text file exists in the folder.

Need help in this. Really would appreciate any help.

Comment: This does not show research effort - a simple google search using your question title turns up the answer. You are welcome to post questions here if you can't find the answer using google!

Comment: i tried and i was unable to do it....thats is why i asked here.

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg Anyone can ask anything. I wouldn't bother telling people what to ask here

Comment: Voting to reopen: this is not off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`EXIST`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/exist.html) function.

```
if exist( fullfile( BASE_DIR, List1(3).name ), 'file' )
  ...
end
```

Comment: does the word file need to be changed to txt?

Comment: @user999450 No, read the documentation in the link I posted. The `file` argument indicates that you're checking whether a file exists, it is not the extension.

Comment: As @Roozi mentioned, the `~= 0` can be left out

Comment: It's better to compare `== 2`, even though `'file'` is specified, because it will return a 7 if it's a directory (in this sense, a directory is a type of file).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`exist()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/exist.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler Code for peaks.mj2 file

```
if exist('peaks.mj2','file')
    delete peaks.mj2
end
```

Comment: why have you post this answer? it adds nothing to this question that does not already exists in the other answer?

Comment: It's simpler than the answers above.

Comment: How exactly is it simpler? it is the same `exist(..., 'file')`

Comment: using if there is no need to check ~=0, simply when something is ~=0 it will be true.

Comment: If we're picking on number of keystrokes, the parentheses around the call to `exist` are unnecessary!